# empty cells and alignment in markdown tables in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This table stopped rendering in Jupyter Notebook version 5.6.0 on Python 3.7 (It still worked fine in April 2018, but I am not sure what version of Jupyter I had)

```
|             | $k$ (m/d) | $z_b$ (m) | $z_t$ | $c$ (days) |
|:-----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|-----------:|
|Aquifer 0    |    2      |     0     |   20  |            |
|Leaky Layer 1|           |    -10    |   0   |   500      |
|Aquifer 1    |    80     |    -30    |   -10 |            |
```

I know need to add something in the empty cells, so the following renders

```
|Layer        | $k$ (m/d) | $z_b$ (m) | $z_t$ | $c$ (days) |
|:-----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|-----------:|
|Aquifer 0    |    2      |     0     |   20  |    -       |
|Leaky Layer 1|    -      |    -10    |   0   |   500      |
|Aquifer 1    |    80     |    -30    |   -10 |   -        |
```

But the first column should be center-aligned and it is right-justified (the colons used to define how the columns align).

Anybody know if things changed? Can we not have empty cells in tables anymore? How can we specify the alignment of columns?

Comment: There seem to be some issues regarding that table alignments: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4130

Comment: thanks. that clarifies the alignment question. the question about an empty cell is still open. anybody?

Comment: To align (e.g. center) an individual cell, you can use `<center>Some cell content</center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both alignment and empty cells work again in the version of Jupyter I have installed (6.0.1). So it is all fixed. Jippy!

Answer (score 2):

The alignment question was solved in version 5.8 of Jupyter.  
Regarding the empty cell you can use `&nbsp;`

Comment: Works. But in my current version of Jupyter (6.0.1) one or more spaces work.